# Allow non-numeric entries in matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I wrote a code that replaces non-numeric values in the matrix by some number.
Now, to test it I would like to allow MATLAB to accept non-numeric entries.

My code starts with prompt:
`matrix_input = input('Please enter the matrix: x=');`

If I enter something like [1,2,3;4,5,?], MATLAB gives an error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket. Since all brackets seem to be balanced, I assume this is due to non-numeric entry. Is it possible to make MATLAB allow non-numeric entries?

Comment: Use `NaN` there to replace those non-numeric entries?

Comment: @Divakar, I already have a code for makeing replacements. My problem is I cannot test it on a matrix with non-numeric entry. I also do not know what character will be used to test my code performance: perhaps '?' or may be something else

Comment: Try a cell instead of a matrix. You can put pretty much anything in a cell. ``c = {1, 2, 3; 4, 5, '?'}``. From there you can do replacements and get a matrix with ``m = cell2mat(c)``.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this matrix?  Give the rest of your use case so we can better help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). Each cell of a cell array can hold any type of data. Curly braces are used to create a cell array like this:

```
cell_array = {1, 2, 3; '4', '?', 6};
```

If you use regular braces to access an element in a cell array you get a cell. If you use curly braces you get the contents of the cell. It's this difference that tends to catch people out with cell arrays.

```
cell_array(1) % Returns a 1x1 cell containing the value 1.
cell_array{1} % Returns 1
```

**EDIT**

Out of curiosity, what code are you using to replace the non-numeric values? For a cell array I came up wit the following:

```
idx = cellfun(@isnumeric, cell_array);
cell_array(~idx) = {NaN};
matrix = cell2mat(cell_array);
```

As mentioned in the comments, you could also use a struct array:

```
struct_array = struct('v', {1, 2, 3; '4', '?', 6});
```

This would create an array of structures where the field `v` contains the value. However, I can't think of a neat way to perform the replacement at the minute.

Comment: You could add arrays of structs as a possible solution. Structs usually perform better than cells.

Comment: Not sure about arrays of structs, but i'm certain that cells have a distinct performance disadvantage vs common structs.

Comment: I'm just checking for isnumeric for some X(i,j), while the loop goes through each row in each column. However, I made a prompt that would ask for entering 'NA' for missing value. So, the problem of checking for '?' is not an issue. (Though this is not the most elegant approach). But thanks for suggestion regarding cell arrays. I'd go with that if I did not do the 'prompt thing'.